# фильтрация вводимой информации от тегов

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как очистить теги с вводимой информации, через jq или на стороне сервера на php. Например в `input-text` вводят `<h1>Тест</h1>`, а нужно, чтобы приходило лишь `Тест` и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  var x = $("#in").val().replace(/< ?[^>]+>/g, "");
  $("#out").text(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="in" />
<button id="click">click</button>
<span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: Да, это работает. Это регулярное выражение?

Comment: @Александр да. выбирает все закрытые таги..(<>)